# Are these HTML files properly configured for user.is_authenticated method in Django

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication

I intend to have extremely sensitive information within my Django website. This being said, I need to restrict access to user accounts only.

Is this a proper configuration for securing my HTML files and sensitive data to the rest of the world?

Django file structure:

[image]

I also have my normal HTML files at the templates level.

**login.html:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login In</title>

</head>
<body>


<form method="POST" style="text-align:center;font-family:verdana;" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        {% load static %}
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}">
    </head>
<body>


    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    {% else %}
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Login <a href="/login" style=";text-decoration:underline;">Here</a></h1>
    {% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

**example.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% block content %}

<html>

<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<h1>Example!</h1>

    <p class='text'>Hello World</p>

</html>

    {% endblock %}
{% else %}
    <p>Login <a href="/login">Here</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to hide sensitive data from non-authorized users and you can also use `@login_required(login_url="<login-url>")` to secure the whole webpage.

You can also his `user role` & `user group` to be more specific about users.

Edit: It depends on your use product, how you want to show your sensitive data